# How to get class name of a object

Tags: php, instanceof

The code:

```
$troll instanceof TrollClass
```

checks whether `$troll` is an instance of `TrollClass`.

How can I tell what class `$troll` is an instance of?

```
$troll instanceof XXXX
```

How can I get `XXXX`?

Comment: The Language is PHP, sorry I forgot to write that.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is PHP:

```
$classname = get_class($troll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "beautiful" is_subclass_of:

bool is_subclass_of ( mixed $object , string $class_name [, bool $allow_string = TRUE ] )

Happy trolling!!